# Unable to match current Date and time in Qt

Tags: qt, datetime, qthread, phonon

I am writing a simple task planner and reminder using Qt which will play a sound file when the date and time of any given task matches with the the current date and time.

To implement this, I am running a `QThread` which checks the task in the list to see if any match the current time and if so, plays the sound file.

This id my original class:

```
class Task
{
  public:
      QString ta, desc;
      QTime ti;
      QDate da;
      int pri, diff;
      bool ala;
};
```

This is my Thread Class:

```
class AlarmCheck : public QThread
{
  public:
      void setTask(QList<Task>);
      void run();
      bool isRunning;
      QString music;
      QTime alarmOffset;

  private:
      QList<Task> list;
};
```

My Implementation:

```
void AlarmCheck::setTask(QList<Task> l)
{
    list = l;
}

void AlarmCheck::run()
{
    while(isRunning)
    {
        foreach(Task t, list)
        {
            if((t.da == QDate::currentDate()) && (t.ti == QTime::currentTime()) && t.ala)
            {
                Phonon::MediaObject *gaana =
                        Phonon::createPlayer(Phonon::MusicCategory,
                                              Phonon::MediaSource(music));
                gaana->play();
                QMessageBox::information(NULL,
                                         "Alarm!!!",
                                         "The time has come for\n"
                                         + t.ta +
                                         "\n Time to do it!");
                gaana->stop();
            }
            qDebug("Curr = " + QTime::currentTime().toString().toAscii() + " Date = " + QDate::currentDate().toString().toAscii());
            qDebug("Task = " + t.ti.toString().toAscii() + " Date = " + t.da.toString().toAscii());                
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

The thing is that the thread is running perfectly, but the `if()` condition inside the `foreach()` loop is never satisfied for some reason. I even checked the individual date/time/alarm setting (`t.ala`) using qDebugs (as you can see); they are all fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement requires that the date and time match *exactly*, down to the millisecond. It is unlikely that your loop will evaluate at this exact moment. If you want to maintain similar logic (processing tasks in a loop), you might try sorting them by "next task first" (or perhaps using a queue), then testing in your `if` statement if the current `QDateTime` is equal-to-*or-greater* than the task date/time of the first task.

Comment: Great one Dave. Thanks a lot for that really witty reply. My one more doubt is that I am actually targeting this to the Symbian s60 5th edition platform; wouldn't this constant 1 second check take a heavy toll on the battery of the phone? if yes, is there any better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Symbian platform's architecture at all. You might want to ask a separate question to get some advice on "best practices" for dealing with timers on that platform. But in general, yes, constantly querying in a loop that will result to "false" 99.9% of the time is not an ideal solution. Usually there is some kind of scheduler API you can tap into, or at least a timer you can poll at less frequent intervals.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I think I will look into the QTimer API. It looks promising!